# Exclusive options in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have a list of checkbox and one of checkbox has value ALL. Whenever ALL is checked then the others of checkbox will be disabled and unchecked (value is empty). How should I do this in AngularJS? A list of checkbox is generated by using a loop over a data list as following:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in moduleService.elements">
    <input type="checkbox">{{item.value}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in moduleService.elements">
    <input id="{{'checkbox' + $index}}" type="checkbox" ng-disabled="allChecked" ng-model="item.isChecked">
    <label for="{{'checkbox' + $index}}">{{item.value}}</label>
</div>
<div>
    <input id="allCheckbox" type="checkbox" ng-model="allChecked" ng-click="onAllClicked()">
    <label for="allCheckbox">All</label>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
var myCtrl = function(moduleService, $scope) {
    $scope.onAllClicked = function() {
        if(!$scope.allChecked) {
            for (var i = 0; i < moduleService.elements.length; i++) {
                moduleService.elements[i].isChecked = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a JSFiddle with similar code: http://jsfiddle.net/robianmcd/W3xeP/

Answer (score 1):

You can use ng-checked, and it makes it sexy.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="masterCheckbox" ng-model="master">

<div ng-repeat="item in moduleService.elements">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="master">{{item.value}}
</div>
```

Nice and easy and clean. Check out the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zargyle/Pb2tq)

Answer (score 0):

you would also need ng-disabled with Zack's answer

```
<input type="checkbox" id="masterCheckbox" ng-model="master">

<div ng-repeat="item in moduleService.elements">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-disabled="master" ng-checked="master">{{item.value}}
</div>
```